# Why does System.out.println(0_101); print 65?

Tags: java

I tried running the code below and I can't figure out why it's printing **65**

```
System.out.println(0_101);
```

Anyone care to shed some light on this?

Comment: It's 101 is an octal literal, its decimal value: 1×8² + 0×8¹ + 1×8⁰ which is 65.

Comment: What do you think it should print? Why do you think so?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, post as an answer! :-)

Comment: @aioobe I didn't want to post it without a JLS evidence :)

Comment: int val=\u0030\u0031\u0030\u0031; System.out.println(val);//65 how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JLS - Chapter 3. Lexical Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.
>
> ...
>
> Underscores may appear after the initial 0 in an octal numeral (since 0 is a digit that denotes part of the integer) and after the initial non-zero digit in a non-zero decimal literal.

So 101 has the decimal value of: 1×8² + 0×8¹ + 1×8⁰, which is 65.

Note that `_` is there only for clarity, it can be used in `int` as well to help reading the number, for example 1000000 vs 1_000_000.

Comment: Whats about this??
int val=\u0030\u0031\u0030\u0031; System.out.println(val);     // it will print 65

Answer (score 0):

It is printint the [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal of `0_101` which as you said is `65`